# Passing in dialog answers for command-line application on launch

Tags: command-line, unix, terminal, buffer

I'm using [pianobar](http://6xq.net/projects/pianobar/) for listening to Pandora from my terminal. On each launch it asks for an email & password. I'd like to pass this information automatically when I launch `pianobar`, so I don't have to type it in each time.

This will allow me to create a small shell script that loads pianobar with the username and password already pre-filled.

Example:

```
> pianobar "you@example.com" "password"
```

How can I accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), which allows you to set responses to interactive command-line programs.